# API to differentiate Jira Cloud and Jira Software (On-Prem)

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-rest-api

I have to pull all Jira fields using REST API. However, the cloud version has "key" keyword in the response but the on-prem version doesn't have it.

Is there any way to identify if the response is from on-prem or cloud.

Note: I have to make multiple Jira API call (to create, pull issue etc), so comparing the "key" keyword won't be a solution for me.

**Sample response from the Jira cloud (while getting fields):**

```
[
    {
        "id": "issuetype",
        "name": "Issue Type",
        "key" : "issuetype",
        "custom": false,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
            "issuetype",
            "type"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "issuetype",
            "system": "issuetype"
        }
    }
]
```

**Sample response from Jira on-prem (while getting fields):**

```
[
    {
        "id": "issuetype",
        "name": "Issue Type",
        "custom": false,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
            "issuetype",
            "type"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "issuetype",
            "system": "issuetype"
        }
    }
]
```

Is there any API to differentiate the version (Cloud or On-Prem)?

Comment: why don't just analyse the url? all Cloud products use XXXXX.atlassian.net

Comment: What you are seeing is the divergence of Jira Cloud and Jira Server. Two separate code bases now. Looks like the Cloud no longer returns the key of some fields, in this case the system Issue Type field. You could check for the presence of a key named "key" in the JSON data and use that

Comment: I see the rest/api/latest/serverInfo resource has a key named "deployment" that has a value of "Server" for Jira Server. That might help

Comment: @mdoar Thank you, this actually helped! 

Thanks for your suggestions Chris :)

Comment: @Kannan Please don't rely on the URL! Jira cloud instances might have a URL of x.atlassian.net (new Jira cloud instances), but also x.jira.com (Jira cloud instances from the old days). Furthermore, it might be possible that you can use custom domains in the future. So you should go ahead with the /serverInfo approach.

Comment: @s.hesse, yes I am aware of it. using /serverInfo API to find the difference. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kannan Excellent. Also wanted to mention that for other users who might read this page here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by @mdoar (on comment section)

"I see the `rest/api/latest/serverInfo` resource has a key named "deployment" that has a value of "Server" for Jira Server. That might help"